# Connectivity error Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've installed MySQL Connector J, WAMP [which comes with MySQL], and Java JDK 1.7 but it always through exception **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

The code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class sou
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       Connection conn = null;
       try
       {
           String userName = "root";
           String password = "";
           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cms";
           Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            conn.close();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println (e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

I'm compiling this as

```
 C:\Users\Sou\Desktop>javac -cp "D:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.20.0\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar" sou.java
```

Comment: It's on the top of the code written with **BOLD FONT**

Comment: it is class name and not an exception

Comment: Oops sorry, my mistake :( I thought _java wanna say it got a prob with the specified class_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` in your CLASSPATH while compiling and running an application.

```
C:\Users\Sou\Desktop>javac -cp .;"D:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.20.0\
                                    mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar" sou.java


C:\Users\Sou\Desktop>java -cp .;"D:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.20.0\
                                    mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar" sou
```

And no need to call the newInstance() method.

```
   Connection conn = null;
   try{
       String userName = "root";
       String password = "";
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cms";
       Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
   }
   catch (Exception e){
       System.err.println (e.getMessage());
   }finally{
       if(conn!=null){
          try{
             conn.close();
          }catch(Exception ex) { }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It works with out the port number too [perhaps works for the default settings only]

Comment: On Java 6 and up there is no need to call `Class.forName()` at all

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

instead of

```
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
```

Comment: **package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist**

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in your program to check for classpath
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));